# ag-Grid IE 10 Cannot Edit Blank Cells

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ag-grid

I cannot edit blank cells or detect clicks on the row when clicking a blank cell.
On IE 11>= and other browsers it works correctly.

Does anyone have idea on what may be the cause here? I do not get any errors or logs in the console, so I am a bit lost on where to start.

Can provide grid creation snippets as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem on my side (refer to [this tutorial](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/)), but I think this issue is related to the ag-Grid plugin, so I suggest you could feedback this issue to [ag-grid issue discuss forum](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues). As a workaround, you could try to set the default value, such as "0" and "Null".

Comment: Setting the default value to any number in this case if blank set to 0, works and they are editable and selectable. The only problem is that when a 0 is entered into a cell I need to be deleting/deactivating records from the system so not sure if this will work as a workaround for me though. But it does work! Thanks! @Dilllion